# How to send an HTTP POST request?

Tags: http, request, http-post, http-get

I have an HTTP GET request, like this:

`http://nom_serveur:port/WSProject/services/nom_service?method=runJob&arg1=--context_param%20user_name=user&arg2=--context_param%20password=pwd&arg3=--context_param%20request_data=CHAINE_XML`

Now, how can I build a POST Request for this example

Answer (score 1):

change your form **method** param from **GET** to **POST**

like this:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "">
//your form elements
</form>
```

**OR**
If you are not building a web page but still want to send *HTTP **POST*** request you can use this chrome-extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

It is very helpful tool like for testing web services.

Comment: thank you for your answer
But i want to know how to pass this request through the browser

Comment: @Yanni you dont have a form but want to pass post request using a browser?